# what should I prefer to specify port about liveness probe and readiness probe when deploy eureka in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am deploy eureka in kubernetes cluster(v1.15.2),this is my yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eureka
  labels:
    app: eureka
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - name: server
      port: 8761
      targetPort: 8761
    - name: management
      port: 8081
  selector:
    app: eureka
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: eureka
  labels:
    app: eureka
spec:
  serviceName: eureka-service
  replicas: 1
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel     #Pod启停顺序管理
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eureka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eureka
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10    #当删除Pod时，等待时间
      containers:
        - name: eureka
          image: registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/soa-eureka:v1.0.0
          ports:
            - name: server
              containerPort: 8761
            - name: management
              containerPort: 8081
          env:
            - name: APP_NAME
              value: "eureka"
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: APP_OPTS
              value: "
                     --spring.application.name=${APP_NAME}
                     --eureka.instance.hostname=${POD_NAME}.${APP_NAME}
                     --registerWithEureka=true
                     --fetchRegistry=true
                     --eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=false
                     --eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-0.${APP_NAME}:8761/eureka/,http://eureka-1.${APP_NAME}:8761/eureka/
                     "
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 2000m
              memory: 1024Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 2000m
              memory: 1024Mi
          readinessProbe:              #就绪探针
            initialDelaySeconds: 20    #延迟加载时间
            periodSeconds: 5           #重试时间间隔
            timeoutSeconds: 10         #超时时间设置
            failureThreshold: 5        #探测失败的重试次数
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health
              port: 8081
          livenessProbe:               #存活探针
            initialDelaySeconds: 60    #延迟加载时间
            periodSeconds: 5           #重试时间间隔
            timeoutSeconds: 5          #超时时间设置
            failureThreshold: 3        #探测失败的重试次数
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health
              port: 8081
```

all service created successfully but give this error message:

```
Readiness probe failed: Get http://172.30.224.17:8081/actuator/health: dial tcp 172.30.224.17:8081: connect: connection refused
Back-off restarting failed container
```

The management port should be the same with eureka service port? what exactly I would do to implement probe service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eureka server is a spring boot application which starts an embedded tomcat and you specify the port in the application.yml of the eureka server. The default port is set to 8761.You can use the 8761 port for probe and that's what I would recommend. You need to have a rest endpoint at `actuator/health` which returns `200 Ok` which I believe added by spring actuator by default so you don't need to implement it yourself.

In short changing the port from 8081 to 8761 in your probe should work.